# How to create settings.php?

Tags: 9, installation

I have installed Drupal with Drush this way

```shell
cd WEB_APPLICATION_ROOT
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project WEB_APPLICATION_DIR_NAME
cd WEB_APPLICATION_DIR_NAME
composer require drush/drush
```

I lack the file settings.php and I understand I need to create it.

Where and how should I create it?

Should I copy `/sites/example.settings.local.php` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only downloaded Drush but didn't use it yet to install Drupal:

```
vendor/bin/drush site:install
```

This creates the settings.php with the database credentials this tool asks for, the same as you are asked when you install Drupal in the web browser.